# Django queryset renders incorrectly. Just displays <QuerySet [<Modelname: Model object (1)>]>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm having a problem with rendering an object from a model.

Here is the model.

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

When I use a queryset like this...

```
QB = Quarterback.objects.all()
```

It doesn't return the object but this instead.

```
<QuerySet [<Quarterback: Quarterback object (1)>]>
```

The object is being saved by a function inside a form.

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):

    quarterback_name = forms.CharField(label='Quarterback', max_length=100)
   
    def save(self):
        quarterback_name = self.cleaned_data.get('quarterback_name')
        Quarterback.objects.create(name=quarterback_name)
```

In my admin panel, I can look up this model object and see that it does indeed have the name of a quarterback saved to the table. I'm not sure why my queryset won't return this though. Perhaps it's the save function causing it?

Comment: It *does*, this is only the *string* relresentation of the object, but if you iterate over the object,s you get teh data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesn't return the object but this instead.

It does, what you here see is the *string* representation of the `QuerySet`, but you can iterate over it, and tese are `Quarterback` objects with the data, for example:

```
for qb in Quarterback.objects.all():
    print((qb.pk, qb.name))
```

By default the `__repr__` implementation of a `Model` object is a `<ModelName: ModelName object (pk)>`. You can however override `__str__` or `__repr__` to show something else, for example:

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you had to iterate over the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a model like this:

```
class Quarterback(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And this returns the QuerySet of the object. If you want it to return the name of your model, in this case `QuarterBack`, you have to add a method to your class, called `__str__`. Here is what it looks like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

This will return a string representation of the model, instead of the queryset.

Comment: Right. But one big problem I've had with returning a string representation of the model is that there is no id to pass. I need to be able to pass the object's id to various functions.

Comment: I dont understand. Id's are given by default to a django model.